# How sort vertices by edge values in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Given the [air-routes](https://github.com/krlawrence/graph) graph, say I want to get all possible one-stopover routes, like so:

```
[home] --distance--> [stopover] --distance--> [destination]
```

where [home], [stopover] and [destination] are airport nodes that each have a property 'code' that represent an airport code; and distance is an integer weight given to each edge connecting two airport nodes.

How could I write a query that gets me the airport codes for [home], [stopover] and [destination] such that the results are sorted as follows:

1. [home] airport codes are sorted alphabetically.
2. For each group of [home] airport, the [stopover] airport codes are sorted by the distance between [home] and [stopover] (ascending).
3. After sorting 1 and 2, [destination] airport codes are sorted by the distance between [stopover] and [destination].

(Note: it doesn't matter if [home] and [destination] are the same airport)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is through `group` with nested `by` modulation.

```
g.V().
  group().
    by('code').
    by(
      outE('route').
      order().by('dist').
      inV().
      group().
        by('code').
        by(
          outE('route').
          order().by('dist').
          inV().
          values('code').fold())).
  unfold()
```

The result is something like:

```
1.  {'SHH': {'WAA': ['KTS', 'SHH', 'OME'], 'OME': ['TLA', 'WMO', 'KTS', 'GLV', 'ELI', 'TNC', 'WAA', 'WBB', 'SHH', 'SKK', 'KKA', 'UNK', 'SVA', 'OTZ', 'GAM', 'ANC']}}
2.  {'KWN': {'BET': ['WNA', 'KWT', 'ATT', 'KUK', 'TLT', 'EEK', 'WTL', 'KKH', 'KWN', 'KLG', 'MLL', 'KWK', 'PQS', 'CYF', 'KPN', 'NME', 'OOK', 'GNU', 'VAK', 'SCM', 'HPB', 'EMK', 'ANC'], 'EEK': ['KWN', 'BET'], 'TOG': ['KWN']}}

3.  {'NUI': {'SCC': ['NUI', 'BTI', 'BRW', 'FAI', 'ANC'], 'BRW': ['ATK', 'AIN', 'NUI', 'PIZ', 'SCC', 'FAI', 'ANC']}}

4.  {'PSG': {'JNU': ['HNH', 'GST', 'HNS', 'SGY', 'SIT', 'KAE', 'PSG', 'YAK', 'KTN', 'ANC', 'SEA'], 'WRG': ['PSG', 'KTN']}}

5.  {'PIP': {'UGB': ['PTH']}}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This put me on the right track for what I was trying to solve. Will accept your answer.